# Target part of a function from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is automatically being brought into my site by a third party add-on.

If some required item within the form on this area are empty, I want to cancel the form submission. I would normally just use return false, but this isn't working, due to this code.

```
window.CartthrobTokenizer = {};
(function(e){
    var ender = require('ender'),
        bean = require('bean'),
        bonzo = require('bonzo'),
        qwery = require('qwery');

    e.form = null;

    e.submissionState = null;

    e.errorHandler = function(errorMessage){
        alert(errorMessage);
    };

    e.setErrorHandler = function(errorHandler){
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
        return this;
    };

    e.submitHandler = function(){
        CartthrobTokenizer.form.submit();
    };

    e.setSubmitHandler = function(submitHandler){
        this.submitHandler = submitHandler;
        return this;
    };

    e.bindHandler = function(){
        return true;
    };

    e.setBindHandler = function(bindHandler){
        this.bindHandler = bindHandler;
        return this;
    };

    e.beforeSubmit = function(){
        return true;
    };

    e.setBeforeSubmit = function(beforeSubmit){
        this.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;
        return this;
    };

    e.addHidden = function(name, value){
        bonzo(CartthrobTokenizer.form).append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\""+name+"\" value=\""+value+"\">");
        return this;
    };

    e.val = function(selector){
        return bonzo(ender(CartthrobTokenizer.form).find(selector)).val();
    };

    e.bind = function(){
        bean.add(CartthrobTokenizer.form, "submit", CartthrobTokenizer.submit);
    };

    e.unbind = function(){
        bean.remove(CartthrobTokenizer.form, "submit", CartthrobTokenizer.submit);
    };

    e.submit = function(e){
        if (CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState === true){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState = true;
        if (CartthrobTokenizer.beforeSubmit() !== false){
            CartthrobTokenizer.bindHandler();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    e.init = function(bindHandler){
        this.form = qwery("#checkout_form").shift();

        this.setBindHandler(bindHandler);

        return CartthrobTokenizer.bind();
    };

})(CartthrobTokenizer);

CartthrobTokenizer.init(function(){
    Stripe.createToken({
        name: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#first_name") + " " + CartthrobTokenizer.val("#last_name"), 
        number: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#credit_card_number"),
        cvc: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#CVV2"),
        exp_month: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#expiration_month"),
        exp_year: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#expiration_year"),
        address_line1: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#address"),
        address_line2: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#address2"),
        address_city:  CartthrobTokenizer.val("#city"),
        address_state: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#state"),
        address_zip: CartthrobTokenizer.val("#zip")
        }, function(status, response){
        if (response.error) {
            CartthrobTokenizer.errorHandler(response.error.message);
            CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState = false;
        } else {
            CartthrobTokenizer.addHidden("stripeToken", response["id"])
                      .addHidden("credit_card_number", response.card["last4"])
                      .addHidden("card_type", response.card["type"])
                      .submitHandler();
        }
    })
});
```

The following seems to be used to stop the form from submitting, within these functions:

```
CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState = false;
```

I have tried to use this, but am unsure how I should call this to get within the third partys functions.

Can anyone explain how I can target the 'submissionstate' function?

Comment: I'm unsure I understand the whole code... It seems to me that the `submissionState` variable is used to know if the form has already been submitted (the value being true once it has been submitted). So you could prevent the submission by setting `CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState = true;`. But you can't set it in `bindHandeler` as this function is called after the checking of the value of `submissionState` in `e.submit`.

Comment: @Sylvain Hi. Thanks for taking a look. If I call 'CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState = true;' or 'CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState = false;' nothing changes. 
Is this possibily because its outside of the function?

Comment: You should not have any problem changing the value of `CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState` . If you want to check if the change are possible you can add : `e.getSubmissionState = function() {console.log(this.submissionState); return this.submissionState};` to your module and call it from outside to see if the changes are applied correctly.

Comment: Now that I think about it... did you change all the `this` with `CartthrobTokenizer` ? It should not make a difference but it's not usefull either, I think. (once again I'm not far from being a begginer so I might be wrong at any moment and all my comment are suggestion more than instructions)

Comment: @Sylvain I have tried to output the state, but get 'e is not defined'. I have not changed any of the 'this' items.

Comment: e is not defined outside the module, you should call `CartthrobTokenizer.submissionState`.